# Can't install latest p7zipfull

Tags: 7zip

Can't find the latest installer for 7zip. Terminal installs one thats 6+ years old. Latest version is 16.02, terminal install 9.2. Does anybody have a link to the latest compatible ubuntu installer

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.7-zip.org/download.html. Download p7zip.

[image]

Extract it. Get a terminal inside the folder. Run below commands.

```
make
sudo make install
```

Then you can use `7za` command which is the latest 7zip program.